# Is there a way to let a user use sudo command in a CentOS docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos7, sudo

I am trying to give iamhappy a sudo privilege as written in the DOCKERFILE however I am receiving the error saying, "`sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?`"  I have set the sticky bit to 1 by executing the command `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo`, but why am I still receiving this error?

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM centos:centos7

# Make sudo work
ARG SUDO_USER=iamhappy
ARG SUDO_USER_PASS=testing
RUN yum install sudo -y && \
    useradd -g wheel ${SUDO_USER} && \
    echo "${SUDO_USER}:${SUDO_USER_PASS}" | chpasswd && \
    sed -i -e 's/^\(%wheel\s\+.\+\)/#\1/gi' /etc/sudoers && \
    echo -e '\n%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo -e '\nDefaults:root   !requiretty' >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo -e '\nDefaults:%wheel !requiretty' >> /etc/sudoers

RUN chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo && chmod a+x /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother.  If you need to get a shell in the container, use the `docker run -u root` or `docker exec -u root` options.  Even that's a little unusual in my experience: a container typically wraps a single process that doesn't need much independent administration, and the sorts of changes that specifically require a root shell often actually require updating and rebuilding the Dockerfile.

Comment: I can't because I am deploying the image in kubernetes.

Comment: You're even less likely to want an interactive shell there: you'll typically have multiple replicas of a service (which one would you run commands in as root?) and a pod can get destroyed without your knowledge (if a node fails or is rotated out; if it needs to move to a different node for scheduling reasons).